# Passing scrapy resutls to mysql databasee

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, variables, scrapy

I'm trying to build a small scraper to sort some news subject as a hobby project (i'm not a professional developer or tech guy and i'm a beginner with OOP and Python, i have some experience with php and arduino programming language). I managed to understand scrapy and partialy mysql pipe. If i replace the item['titlu'] and item['articol'] with a simple string, database will be populated with that. I had search and read a lot of info but i'm totally unable to solve my problem.
I suppose that  item['titlu'] and item['articol'] are some type of array or something that mysql does not like. i will post the code  and errors for help.
The commented lines of code are some of my trials to solve the problem
mysql database table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `ziare_com` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titlu` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `articol` varchar(20000) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
```

I have also tryed to change titlu and articol text type to varchar. In purpose i have let the table example like this(with one filde text and other varchar) for you to know what settings i have tryed.

Thanks:

spider:

```
  def parse(self, response):
     #pass
     for link in response.xpath('//h2[@class="titlu_sec"]/a/@href').extract():
         yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_detail)
 def parse_detail(self, response):
     item = RezultScrap()
     #for quote in response.css('div.quote')
     item['titlu'] = response.css(".titlu_stire::text").extract()
     item['articol'] = response.css(".descriere_main::text").extract()
     return item

         #item['titlu'] = response.xpath('//div[contains(@id, "interior_left")]/h1/text()').extract_first()
         #item['articol'] = response.xpath('//div[contains(@id, "content_font_resizable")]//text()').extract()
     #titlu = response.css(".titlu_stire::text").extract()
     #articol = response.css(".descriere_main::text").extract()
         #yield item
     #titul1 = re.sub(r"['\\]","", titlu)
     #articol1 =  re.sub(r"['\\]","", articol)


    # yield {
     #        'titlu':titlu,
      #       'articol':articol
             #titlu,
             #articol
     #}
```

items.py:

```
import scrapy


 class FirstItem(scrapy.Item):
     # define the fields for your item here like:
     # name = scrapy.Field()
     pass
 class RezultScrap(scrapy.Item):
     titlu=scrapy.Field()
     articol=scrapy.Field()
```

pipelines.py:

```
import pymysql
 #from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
 #pmysql.escape_string("'")
 from first.items import RezultScrap


 class Mysql(object):
         def __init__(self):
             self.connection = pymysql.connect("localhost","xxxxxx","xxxx","ziare")
             self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()


         def process_item(self, item, spider):
             #titlu1 = [pymysql.escape_string(item['titlu'])]
             #articol1 = [pymysql.escape_string(item['articol'])]
             #self.cursor.execute
             #query ="INSERT INTO ziare_com (titlu, articol) VALUES (%s, %s)"
             query ="INSERT INTO ziare_com (titlu, articol) VALUES (%s, %s) % (item['titlu'], item['articol'])"
             self.cursor.execute(query)
             #self.cursor.executemany(query)
             self.connection.commit()
             #return item

         def close_spider(self, spider):
             self.cursor.close()
             self.connection.close()
```

The erors are as follows:

This one is when i use self.cursor.executemany(query)

> TypeError: executemany() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'args'

and this is when I use **self.cursor.execute(query)**
I get this:

> pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s) % (item['titlu'],
>   item['articol'])' at line 1")

Comment: Try to set quotes around variables and move out tuple from your string: 'INSERT INTO ziare_com (titlu, articol) VALUES ("%s", "%s")' % (item['titlu'], item['articol'])

Answer (score 0):

Correct code in process_item is

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):

    query ="INSERT INTO ziare_com (titlu, articol) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    self.cursor.execute(query, [ item['titlu'], item['articol'] ])
    self.connection.commit()
    return item
```

You just have to write `%s` for values and then pass them as a list (array) in `execute` method

Moreover, you should learn about string formatting

You were doing

```
"INSERT INTO ziare_com (titlu, articol) VALUES (%s, %s) % (item['titlu'], item['articol'])"
```

That entire is a string, you are not passing values to your string at all

here is corrected statement

```
"INSERT INTO ziare_com (titlu, articol) VALUES (%s, %s) " % ((item['titlu'], item['articol']))
```